# Component variable not updated in template (on mobile)

Tags: android, angular, capacitor

In my template I have a div with an ngIf:

```html
<button (click)="toggleExit()">Click</button>

<div class="exitModal" *ngIf="exitConfirmation">
  <button (click)="toggleExit()">Stay</button>
</div>
```

In the component I have a Capacitor listener for the mobile back button:

```js
public ngOnInit(): void {
  CapacitorApp.addListener('backButton', ({ canGoBack }) => {
    if (canGoBack) {
      window.history.back()
    } else {
      this.exitConfirmation = true;
      console.log('exitConfirmation: ', this.exitConfirmation)
    };
  });
}

public toggleExit(): void {
  this.exitConfirmation = !this.exitConfirmation;
}
```

Fairly simple. The listener is called when the back button on a phone is used. `canGoBack` Indicates whether the browser can go back in history. False when the history stack is on the first entry. So when `canGoBack` is false then we're on the first entry and I want to show the exit confirmation element.

when I call the `toggleExit()` function from the template the `exitConfirmation` boolean value *is* changed in the template.

But when that same `exitConfirmation` boolean is changed in the class in the `CapacitorApp.addListener` then the value is *not* changed in the template. AndroidStudo shows the change in the log:

> http://localhost/main.8f254a4bebe3e3fe.js - Line 1 - Msg: exitConfirmation:  true

But the variable is not changed in the template until I trigger `changeDetection`

Answer (score 0):

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/angular

> Capacitor plugin event listeners run outside of Angular's NgZone execution context

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the code of changing your variable is not running inside angular zone.
To run things inside the zone use:

```js
// inject via: zone = inject(NgZone);
this.zone.run(() => {
     /* your code here */
});
```